# list of buttons scrollable android

Tags: android, button, scroll

I am new to android development and coding so go easy.

I have a list of buttons, they are each the width of the screen from top to bottom, but I want to add more, and have the user be able to scroll down further to see more choices, how can I do this after I have already made everything else? Is there some easy way I can just put all my buttons in a scrollable format so I can slide my finger up or down to see more buttons/choices?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, but how do I now add a medium text above the buttons and a separate button(that doesn't scroll) at the bottom of the screen? Do I need to make another 2 LinearLayouts just for a medium text and another separate button? Otherwise if I put it in the current LinearLayout it will scroll as it's within the ScrollView?

Much appreciated!

Comment: @spergy It should be a separate question. Late replying :P

Answer (score 0):

Just create a (vertical) `ScrollView`, add a (vertical) `LinearLayout` as its child, and add the buttons to that `LinearLayout`. All this can be done directly in your layout xml.

Comment: Thanks guys, but how do I now add a medium text above the buttons and a separate button(that doesn't scroll) at the bottom of the screen? Do I need to make another 2 LinearLayouts just for a medium text and another separate button? Otherwise if I put it in the current LinearLayout it will scroll as it's within the ScrollView?

Much appreciated!